# Streamlit - как получить ссылку?

Tags: python, pip, streamlit

Начинаю работу с Streamlit на Python.
Пишу

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit
```

Ошибка не выдается, все скачивается. Сегодня же скачивала другой пакет через pip, проблем не было.
Далее пишу простейший код

```
import streamlit as st
st.write('Hello, world!')
```

Насколько я понимаю, у меня должна появиться ссылка на страницу, где высвечивается фраза, но ссылки нет. Что я делаю не так? Пишу в Jupiter, может ли проблема быть связана с ним?

UPD: изменила переменные среды теперь пишет

```
C:\Users\асер>pip install --upgrade streamlit
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting streamlit
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/streamlit/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/streamlit/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/streamlit/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/streamlit/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/streamlit/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/streamlit/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/streamlit/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for streamlit
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы запустить ваш код, выполните команду в консоле

```
streamlit run main.py
```

Где `main.py` это имя стартового файла с кодом

```
import streamlit as st
st.write('Hello, world!')
```

Comment: Пишет: "streamlit" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Хотя pip install прошел

Comment: @jane по какой-то причине консоль не видит установленный модуль. Вероятно, место установки и запуск команды происходят в разных окружениях. Например, модуль был установлен в виртуальном окружении `venv`, а запустить вы пытаетесь из обычной консоли.

Comment: Ccылка по умолчанию должна быть: http://localhost:8501 или http://127.0.0.1:8501.

Answer (score 0):

Ccылка по умолчанию должна быть: http://localhost:8501 или http://127.0.0.1:8501.